# Show password characters for a short while before hiding them

Tags: android, android-edittext, transformation

In my application I've implemented a num-pad of my own, which is used for entering (number-based) passcodes. The 'password', or rather the 'dot'-representation of it, is shown on 4 EditTexts implemented in 4 boxes above the num-pad. When you enter a number one of those boxes will get filled in with a dot - for this I use the TransformationMethod PasswordTransformationMethod - but I'd want the number you punch in to be visible for a short while before it gets hidden (Like ~200ms).

Is there any implementation of this readily-done in Android or how would you implement this the best way? I'm sure you know what I mean, it's used quite frequently for mobile-based password entering.

Edit: Code after tips:

```
codeField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode_1);
codeField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode_2);
codeField3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode_3);
codeField4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passcode_4);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            codeField1.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            codeField2.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            codeField3.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            codeField4.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
       }
    }, 2000);
```

Still giving me issues, only effect on the first one I enter.. (All this is in onCreate()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code ..

this will hide the text after 2 second and you can change it based on your requi..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
    }, 2000);  // set time based on your requirement
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put that code-snippet? Where I initiate my EditTexts or in my onClick().. ? Or somewhere else? Havent really worked with Handlers before

Comment: Okay, so I put it inside my onCreate() after I've initiated all my EditTexts - and the effect works, but only for my first Edit Text. Seems really strange.. Edit: I put all my editTexts after eachother in run()

Comment: put all your edittext inside that and make sure that all the edittext is initialed

Comment: It working with me dude.. i hve tried..  try my updated code

Comment: Finally got it to work, although I had to set a new separate handler for every separate EditText, really strange. Thanks alot for your help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use [TextWatcher](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html)

Do not set the   `android:password="true"` property in edittext.Instead use a **textwatcher** and in the **addTextChangedListener()** of the textwatcher **replace the password with *** after waiting for 200ms.

To wait use the following code:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
 mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doStuff();
            }
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Focused entirely on the other solution since it came in like 30 seconds before yours, lol - but it seems you were onto something similar. Thanks for reaching out!