# Android - EditText get physical length when type is password

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the physical length (in pixel) of the value of an EditText, but when it's a password I get the length of the value of the password, not the length of all the dots.

For exemple, I put "Hello" in my edit text, when I try to get it's length it's the same as doing :

```
paint.measureText("Hello");
```

But I want to get the length of this
[image]

*"Password :" is a prefix I added, it's not into the EditText value itself*

If someone could help me, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So, in your example, you want to get back "5" (the number of dots)?

Comment: Okay I didn't explain myself very well, I want to get the length in pixel :)

Comment: Length in pixels of what? The whole edit text? The start of the first dot to the end of the last dot?

Comment: Yes, and you should know that "Password :" is not return in the `edittext.getText()` method

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23923053/833647

Comment: Just tried it and it's the same problem, it will give the length of "Hello" not of the dots :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the actual character printed by the password EditText will be one of the Unicode Bullet characters. So for instance, if it is U+2022, then you can use.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int n = inputPassword.getText().length();
while (n-- > 0) sb.append('\u2022');

double width = inputPassword.getPaint()
        .measureText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: I think that it's what I wanted thanks !
But do you know if it's possible to detect when the last character of the EditText become a dot ? :)

Comment: Sadly I'm not sure how to make that happen.

Comment: @LeoAso That was a smart one!

Comment: @RayKytto [Refer this for text to dot delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38768120/show-password-characters-for-a-short-while-before-hiding-them).

Comment: @Journey I just tried it, but even if I change the value, the time the app wait to hide the text stay the same.
And I don't really want to change the time it take to be hiden, just detect when it does

Comment: plus-one for the while(n-- > 0)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Rect bounds = new Rect(); 
Paint textPaint = edittext.getPaint(); 
textPaint.getTextBounds(edittext.getText().toString(), 
0,edittext.getText().length(), bounds); 
int height = bounds.height();
int width = bounds.width(); Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+width, 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I don't want the number of characters, but the width in pixels

Comment: Rect bounds = new Rect();
                Paint textPaint = edittext.getPaint();
                textPaint.getTextBounds(edittext.getText().toString(), 0,edittext.getText().length(), bounds);
                int height = bounds.height();
                int width = bounds.width();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, ""+width, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

*Unfortunately, it only returns the length of painted font not the dots.

```
content = editText.getText();
Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint textPaint = editText.getPaint();
textPaint.getTextBounds(content, 0, content.length(), bounds);
int width = bounds.width();// This is the the length of the contents in pixels(painted).
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already tried it but it returns the length in pixels of the hiden text, not of the dots :/